# JavaScript Routing in Zurb Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-6

I'm getting into Zurb's Foundation for a client, and I'm wondering if it has any concept of routing JavaScript to specific pages. I've semi- built my own framework that routes JavaScript for specific pages, only loading what's needed for the current page.

I'm seeing Angular mentioned often; would this be addressed by that? Any help is appreciated! Feel free to tell me if this needs more clarification; again I'm just getting into Foundation, and can't seem to find if this is addressed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Zurb Foundation is a responsive front-end framework. You load what is needed depending on your plugins or not usage. 
If you have developed your own system of including js' that you need based on the page you could certainly use it with foundation.

Your second question could be answered by visiting the [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org) site and reading about the framework. It is more of a MVC emulation system to support a dynamic html approach.

Comment: I see; so Foundation doesn't cover discrete javascript, but instead loads it depending on what plugins/modules are used on the requested page?

Comment: Sorry, Taylor. Responsive is referring to the mobile first / small screen device rendering that has the ability to render on medium and large screens too. 'You load' refers to you as the developer loading the scripts needed in the page. You know what plugins you are using so you make sure the script is loaded. I hope that is less ambiguous.